# validation error prints {{errors}} rather than the real error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After having something upgraded from underneath me (unfortunately, I'm not sure what), validation errors now print the following:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: {{errors}}
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:1102:in `save_without_dirty!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/dirty.rb:87:in `save_without_transactions!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:136:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:182:in `transaction'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:200:in `save!'
    from (irb):34
    from :0
```

I'm setting the error like this:

```
errors.add_to_base("outside edit window")
```

This used to work, what am I doing wrong? this is on rails 2.3.8.

Comment: In what context are you making the call to `errors.add_to_base("outside edit window")` Ie. in what method, what's the surrounding code etc.?

Comment: I think you are calling `save!` or `create!` instead of `save` or `create`. This will invoke exception if the validations are not satisfied.

Comment: I have a model which has `validate :edit_window` and I'm doing the check and the `errors.add_to_base` in the `edit_window` function

Comment: I am calling `save!`, I do want the exception, I just also want to it to tell me which validation failed.

Comment: See Glenn's answer below. Upgrade Rails or downgrade i18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link explaining the problem;
  https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/71

You should either downgrade your i18n gem to 0.3.3, or upgrade your Rails version > 2.3.8

Comment: Good to see you on SO Glenn. Your first answer and your first upvote!